# Footable Pagination Not Showing at all

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, footable

I am struggling to show footable pagination and still can't figure it out even though I checked documentation and all other examples. In the following code, two tables are tried in different ways and both don't show pagination. Does anyone could explain and point out what is needed to show pagination in this code ? Thanks.

```
<html lang="en">
    <head>
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-footable/3.1.6/footable.bootstrap.min.css">
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-footable/3.1.6/footable.core.bootstrap.min.css">
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-footable/3.1.6/footable.paging.css">
    </head>


    <body>
        <table class="table footable table-striped" data-paging="true">
                <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th data-breakpoints = "xs">Col 1</th>
                            <th data-breakpoints = "xs">Col 2</th>
                            <th data-breakpoints = "xs">Col 3</th>  
                        </tr>

                </thead>
                <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td>test1</td>
                            <td>test2</td>
                            <td>test3</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                                <td>test1</td>
                                <td>test2</td>
                                <td>test3</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                    <td>test1</td>
                                    <td>test2</td>
                                    <td>test3</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                        <td>test1</td>
                                        <td>test2</td>
                                        <td>test3</td>
                                    </tr>   

                    </tbody>
                    <tfoot>

                    </tfoot>
        </table>
        <table id="tblTesting" class="testingTable table table-striped" data-paging="true" data-page-navigation=".pagination" >
        </table>



<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-footable/3.1.6/footable.js"></script>
<script src= "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-footable/3.1.6/footable.paging.js"></script>


    </body>
</html>

<script>

    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.footable').footable();


       $('#tblTesting').footable({
        paging:{"enabled": true},
        columns:[
  {"name":"id","title":"ID","breakpoints":"xs sm","type":"number","style":{"width":80,"maxWidth":80}},
  {"name":"firstName","title":"First Name"},
  {"name":"lastName","title":"Last Name"},
  {"name":"something","title":"Never seen but always around","visible":false,"filterable":false},
  {"name":"jobTitle","title":"Job Title","breakpoints":"xs sm","style":{"maxWidth":200,"overflow":"hidden","textOverflow":"ellipsis","wordBreak":"keep-all","whiteSpace":"nowrap"}},
  {"name":"started","title":"Started On","type":"date","breakpoints":"xs sm md","formatString":"MMM YYYY"},
  {"name":"dob","title":"Date of Birth","type":"date","breakpoints":"xs sm md","formatString":"DD MMM YYYY"},
  {"name":"status","title":"Status"}
],
"rows":[
  {"id":1,"firstName":"Annemarie","lastName":"Bruening","something":1381105566987,"jobTitle":"Cloak Room Attendant","started":1367700388909,"dob":122365714987,"status":"Suspended"},
{"id":1,"firstName":"Annemarie","lastName":"Bruening","something":1381105566987,"jobTitle":"Cloak Room Attendant","started":1367700388909,"dob":122365714987,"status":"Suspended"},
{"id":1,"firstName":"Annemarie","lastName":"Bruening","something":1381105566987,"jobTitle":"Cloak Room Attendant","started":1367700388909,"dob":122365714987,"status":"Suspended"}
]

    });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: have you debug your application through your browser?

Comment: Yes, no js error and no pagination. I've struggling like for five days to show pagination.

Comment: you include the pagination because it seems that you didn't declared it

Comment: What are you hoping to achieve? Are you wanting to show one column at a time? Are you wanting to load only 3 rows at a time and then load another 3 as required?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's just because the data is small, try populating with over 10 or smth like that. Most pagination plugins use 10 for default.